# Some questions about the internals of bcrypt

Tags: bcrypt

I'm attempting to get a better understanding of cryptography and have run into some questions about bcrypt.

Bcrypt relies on the blowfish cipher, which is a reversible method of encryption. But bcrypt is not reversible. How is that possible? Or am I mistaken? What does bcrypt do on top of blowfish to make it irreversible?

Why does bcrypt use blowfish instead of twofish or threefish?